# Fast algorithm for computing Kendall Tau distance between two integer sequences

Tags: algorithm

I am given two sequences of integers with equal length, e.g.

> 3 1 2 5 4
>
> 5 3 2 1 4

I want to find the Kendall Tau distance between the two, i.e. the number of inverted pairs between the sequences. For instance, we have (3, 5) (3 is before 5) in the first sequence and (5, 3) in the second one. I did a quick O(n^2) algorithm to check the number, but it gets too computationally intense for large sequences of length 40,000 and on. I've read that I can count the number of inversions in doing a bubble sort, transforming the first sequence into the second one, but that's yet again O(n^2).

```
  unsigned short n, first[50001], second[50001], s;
  int sum = 0;
  cin >> n;
  for(int i=1; i<n+1; i++){
        cin >> first[i];
  }
  // in the second array exchange the actual entries in the sequence with their indices
  // that way we can quickly check if a pair is inverted
  for(int i=1; i<n+1; i++){
        cin >> s
        second[s]=i;
  }
  for(int i=1; i<n+1; i++){
      for (int j = i+1; j < n+1; j++)
        // i < j always
        // when we check the indices of the respective entries in the second array
        // the relationship should stay otherwise we have an inversion
        if(second[first[i]]>=second[first[j]])sum++;
  }
```

Comment: that solved the problem, thanks a lot

Comment: Since you seem to be after code rather than an algorithm, I'm migrating this question to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem seems closely related to the problem of counting inversions in an array, with the difference being that in this case an inversion means "the elements are swapped relative to the other sequence" rather than "the elements are out of order." Since there's a nice O(n log n)-time algorithm for counting inversions, it seems like it would be reasonable to try to find a way to adapt that algorithm to solve this particular problem.

The divide-and-conquer algorithm for counting inversions is based on mergesort and assumes that given any two elements in the sequence there's a fast (O(1)-time) way to compare them to see if they're in the proper order. If we can find a way to somehow annotate the elements of the second sequence so that in time O(1) we can determine whether any pair of elements from that sequence are in order or out of order, then we can just run the fast counting inversions algorithm to get the answer you're looking for.

Here's one way to do this. Create some auxiliary data structure (say, a balanced BST) that associates the elements of the first array with their indices in the first array. Then, make a copy of the second array, annotating each element with its corresponding position in the first array. This in total takes time O(n log n). Then, run the standard O(n log n)-time algorithm for counting inversions in the second array, except when comparing elements, compare by their associated index rather than their values. This in total takes time O(n log n) to complete.